# strange echo output

Tags: unix, echo

Can anybody explain this behaviour of the bash shell which is driving me nuts

```
[root@ns1 bin]# export test=`whois -h whois.lacnic.net 187.14.6.108 | grep -i inetnum: | awk '{print $2}'`

[root@ns1 bin]# echo $test
187.12/14

[root@ns1 bin]# echo "iptables -I INPUT -s $test -J DROP"

-J DROP -I INPUT -s 187.12/14

[root@ns1 bin]#
```

Why is my `echo` screwed up? It is being changed by the contents of `$test`.

If you change `$test` to "ABC" all is fine. Is it related to the slash?

Comment: I suspect there may be some nonvisible characters in `$test` such as a carriage return, which causes `-J DROP` to backup and overwrite `iptables` on the output. In other words, that "187.12/14" string is probably something like "\r187.12.14" or something like that.

Comment: @devnull - nothing to do with | - I think mbratch is correct

Comment: @JimHolland The formatting caused the backticks (command substitution) to be _invisible_.  I was led to think that you're using a command with `|` as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my `echo` screwed up? It is being changed by the contents of
>   `$test`.

Because your `test` contains a carriage return.  Remove it:

```
test=$(whois -h whois.lacnic.net 187.14.6.108 | grep -i inetnum: | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` contains something like

```
1234567 -I INPUT -s 187.12/14\r-J DROP
```

which, due to the carriage return, is visible only as

```
-J DROP -I INPUT -s 187.12/14
```

The CR moves the cursor to the start-of-line, where it then overwrites previous characters.

You could try

```
echo "$test" | od -bc
```

to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a carriage return. `echo` is doing its job correctly and emitting the string to your terminal; the problem is that your terminal is treating a part of the string as a command for it to follow (specifically, a LF character, `$'\r'`, telling it to send the cursor to the beginning of the existing line).

If you want to see the contents of `$test` in a way which doesn't allow your terminal to interpret escape sequences or other control characters, run the following (note that the `%q` format string is a bash extension, not available in pure-POSIX systems):

```
printf '%q\n' "$test"
```

This will show you the precise contents formatted and escaped for use by the shell, which will be illuminative as to why they are problematic.

To remove `$'\r'`, which is almost certainly the character giving you trouble, you can run the following parameter expansion:

```
test=${test//$'\r'/}
```

Unlike solutions requiring piping launching an extra process (such as `tr`), this happens inside the already-running bash shell, and is thus more efficient.